# comparing two files based on column if $3 of file1 is <0 in awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

comparing two files based on column 2nd of file1. if $3 of file1 is <0 and $3 of file2 is 'n' then print of row file2, else if $3 of file1 is >0 and $3 of file2 is 'p' then print of row file2 else null print.

file1

```
1;  a; -16;
2;  b; -3;
3;  c; -4; 
4;  d;  5;
```

file2

```
1; a;  n;
2; b;  n;
3; c;  p;
4; d;  p;
5; e;  p;
```

output look like:

```
1; a; n;
2; b; n;
4; d; p;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F'; *' 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$3;next}$3=="n" && a[$2]<0 || $3=="p" && a[$2]>0' file1 file2
1; a;  n;
2; b;  n;
4; d;  p;
```

Store 3rd column of file one indexed at 2nd column in an array. For the second file, just test your condition. If either is true, `awk` by default will print the line for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple script and get your result.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    while 
    read -r lineA <&3          
    read -r lineB <&4       
    do
    val1=`echo "$lineA" | cut -d";" -f3`
    val2=`echo "$lineB" | cut -d";" -f3`
    if [ -n "$val1" ] && [ -n "$val2" ] ; then
            if [ $val1 -lt 0 ] && [ $val2 == "n" ]  ; then
                    echo  "$lineB" 
            elif [ $val1 -gt 0 ] && [ $val2 == "p" ]  ;then
                    echo "$lineB" ;
            fi
    fi

  done 3<a.txt 4<b.txt
```

Comment: **Thanks to Kalanidhi M. **